# In Primefaces, all the radiobuttons are getting selected automatically

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am following the example given [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionRadioCheckbox.jsf). I have to show CheckBox and RadioButton for a list of Employees, where user can select many CheckBoxs, but only one RadioButton. Just the normal behaviour. I started with Radiobutton first and after running all my radiobuttons are selected automatically.

I have the below index.xhtml page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <f:event listener="#{userPreferenceBean.preRender}" type="preRenderView" />
    <h:head>
        <title>Datatable with Checkbox and RadioButton Example</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <p:dataTable id="employeeDataTable" var="employee" value="#{userPreferenceBean.employeeList}"
                rowKey="#{userPreferenceBean.employeeDataModel}" paginator="true" rows="10" 
                selection="#{userPreferenceBean.selectedEmployeeList}">

                <f:facet name="header">
                    Showing employee List
                </f:facet>

                <p:column selectionMode="single" style="width:2%"></p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Name" style="width:48%">
                    #{employee.name}
                </p:column>

                <p:column headerText="Department" style="width:48%">
                    #{employee.department}
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </h:form>

    </h:body>
</html>
```

My Backing bean is:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class UserPreferenceBean implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private List<Employee> employeeList;
    private List<Employee> selectedEmployeeList;
    private EmployeeDataModel employeeDataModel;

    public void preRender(ComponentSystemEvent ebent){
        System.out.println("Inside prerender");
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void initializeEmployeeList(){
        createEmployeeList();
        employeeDataModel = new EmployeeDataModel(employeeList);
    }

    private void createEmployeeList(){
        employeeList = new ArrayList<>();
        employeeList.add(new Employee("Sudipta",29,"Computer"));
        employeeList.add(new Employee("Bunty", 29, "Electrical"));
        employeeList.add(new Employee("Pradipta", 24, "Computer"));
    }

        //Other Getter and Setters
```

Below is the POJO Class of Employee:

```
public class Employee implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String department;
        //Constructor and Getters+Setters
```

And this is my DataModel class:

```
public class EmployeeDataModel extends ListDataModel<Employee> implements SelectableDataModel<Employee>{

    public EmployeeDataModel(){

    }

    public EmployeeDataModel(List<Employee> employees){
        super(employees);
    }

    @Override
    public Employee getRowData(String rowKey) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Employee> employees = (List<Employee>) getWrappedData();
        for(Employee employee : employees){
            if(employee.getName().equals(rowKey))
                return employee;
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getRowKey(Employee employee) {
        return employee.getName();
    }

}
```

Do you have any idea why all radiobuttons are getting selected automatically and what changes I need to do? Thanks. Attached is the screenshot[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to have a list of radiobuttons where only 1 can be selected and then 1 checkbox to select all the radiobuttons. Normal behavior with radiobuttons is that only 1 can be selected. If you only use checkboxes this is possible, but even then only the displaying page will be selected. You can test this in the showcase.

If I were you I would implement the solution with only the checkboxes.

Comment: I tried that it is giving me below error message                               java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "name"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
 at javax.el.ListELResolver.toInteger(ListELResolver.java:409)
 at javax.el.ListELResolver.getValue(ListELResolver.java:202)
 at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
 at

Comment: I updated my answer because i think you need a different approach.

Comment: My requirement is not to have 1 checkbox to select all radiobuttons. Rather my requirement is to give users option to chosse many Employees as his/her favourite by selected multiple checkboxes, but select only 1 radiobutton to make one Employee as his/her primary employee. Hope it is clear now.

Comment: And should this both happen in 1 datatable?

Comment: Then you should have a column with radiobuttons and a column with checkboxes and that just isn't gonna work. Use the checkboxes to let the user select his favorite employees. To select his primary employee you could add a row with commanbuttons were you need to click to select and unselect the employee. Or gove him a selectOne menu to select the primary employee.

Comment: I am able to achieve the functionality. But I also think in the same datatable, RadioButton and CheckBox are not possible. So I made a column with CheckBox to select list of Favourite Employees and another column with CommandButton to select Primary Employee. The code is working fine now. Here is the full source code @ [link] https://github.com/suddeb/Primeface_And_JSF/tree/master/PrimefaceDataTableAdvance

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the `employeeDataModel` properly, your `value` attribute of the table should be init in the following way

`value="#{userPreferenceBean.employeeDataModel}"`

and I think you can remove the `rowKey` attribute

Take a look at the following example [DataTable - Instant Row Selection](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionInstant.jsf)

Comment: This is how employeeDataModel is defined inside backing bean.     `private EmployeeDataModel employeeDataModel;` So if I make `value="#{userPreferenceBean.employeeDataModel}"` this will give me ClassCastException `java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.sudipta.metadata.Employee`

Comment: If you see my backing bean, it is like this below                                `private EmployeeDataModel employeeDataModel;                                                                              @PostConstruct
    public void initializeEmployeeList(){
        createEmployeeList();
        employeeDataModel = new EmployeeDataModel(employeeList);
    }`

Comment: did you removed the `rowKey` from the table?

Comment: Yes. Still the same problem

Comment: the exception should point to a specific row in your code, what row is it and what code is written there ? is it pointing to your `@PostConstruct` .... new EmployeeDataModel(employeeList); line ?

Comment: The exception is coming from @PostConstruct method. The exact line is: employeeDataModel = new EmployeeDataModel(employeeList);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37005/discussion-between-sudipta-deb-and-daniel)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I am able to solve the problem. The problem was below:
Since my selectionMode was single like

```
<p:column selectionMode="single" style="width:2%"></p:column>
```

so I need `selection="#{userPreferenceBean.selectedEmployee}"` rather than the list of employees.

Now the index.xhtml looks like:

```
<p:dataTable id="employeeDataTable" var="employee" value="#{userPreferenceBean.employeeDataModel}"
            paginator="true" rows="10" selection="#{userPreferenceBean.selectedEmployee}">

            <f:facet name="header">
                    Showing employee List
                </f:facet>

            <p:column selectionMode="single" style="width:2%" />

            <p:column headerText="Name" style="width:48%">
                    #{employee.name}
                </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Department" style="width:48%">
                    #{employee.department}
                </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
```

And I added the below member in my backing bean.

```
private Employee selectedEmployee; with getters and setters. Now it is working fine.
```

Full code is @ [myGitHubRepo](https://github.com/suddeb/Primeface_And_JSF)

Thanks.